# Add column to data frame with multiple conditions and formulas based on earlier rows

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

So I have data wrangling question.

Here is my example data.

```
year <- c(2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021)
sn <- c("AB1001", "AB1002", "AB1001", "DC1001", "AB1002", "AB1001", "AB1003")
hours <- c(150, 173, 189, 102, 175, 215, 98)
delta_hours <- c(150, 173, 39, 102, NA, NA, NA)
df <- data.frame(year, sn, hours, delta_hours)
```

which produces this data frame:

```
year     sn hours delta_hours
1 2019 AB1001   150         150
2 2019 AB1002   173         173
3 2020 AB1001   189          39
4 2020 DC1001   102         102
5 2021 AB1002   175          NA
6 2021 AB1001   215          NA
7 2021 AB1003    98          NA
```

What I am needing to do is mutate/update the delta_hours column for 2021. Specifically, for sn's that are unique (haven't been in previous years) I want to be able to simply copy over the information from the hours column. For those sn's that have appeared in previous years, I want to subtract the hours from the 2021 year by the hours in whatever the most recent year was. So for sn `AB1001`, I would want to take `215 - 189` in order to get `26`. For sn `AB1003` I want to simply copy over the `98`. And of course for any year prior to 2021, I wan to simply keep the information.

My final data frame should basically look like this:

```
year     sn hours delta_hours
1 2019 AB1001   150         150
2 2019 AB1002   173         173
3 2020 AB1001   189          39
4 2020 DC1001   102         102
5 2021 AB1002   175           2
6 2021 AB1001   215          26
7 2021 AB1003    98          98
```

I'm assuming I need to use `case_when`, and I can do that to get the data from prior years to simply copy over, but I'm not getting how to do the subtraction properly.

Help appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(sn) %>% 
  mutate(
    delta_hours = if_else(year == 2021, hours - lag(hours), delta_hours),
    delta_hours = if_else(is.na(delta_hours), hours, delta_hours)
  )

# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   sn [4]
   year sn     hours delta_hours
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>       <dbl>
1  2019 AB1001   150         150
2  2019 AB1002   173         173
3  2020 AB1001   189          39
4  2020 DC1001   102         102
5  2021 AB1002   175           2
6  2021 AB1001   215          26
7  2021 AB1003    98          98
```

Comment: I had to make a slight modification to my real data because of an extra nuance, so I combined this with `case_when` inside `mutate()` in a second step, but I did not know about the `lag()` function, and that's what I really needed. Thanks!